# "Open in Visio " & "Open in Excel" is not working, and I will get an error message

Tags: 2013, excel-services, configuration, office-integration, visio-services

I have the following inside my SharePoint server 2013 :-

- EnterPrise Wiki site collection.
- i have both "Excel services Application "& "Visio Graphics Service" running correctly.

The problem i am facing is as follow:-

1. when a user click on an Excel sheet or Visio document , it will be shown inside the browser without any problem.
2. but if the user click on "Open in Visio" OR "Open in Excel" links inside the browser, they will get the following errors:-

> Sorry, but to open this workbook, your computer must be running a
>   supported version of Microsoft Excel and a browser that supports
>   opening files directly from Office Web Apps.

&

> To open this document, your computer must be running a supported
>   version of Microsoft Visio and a browser that supports opening files
>   directly from Visio Web Access.

[image]

I have the following settings inside my PC:-

1. Office 2010 for Excel, word, power point,etc.
2. Visio 2013.
3. i have disabled SharePoint foundation support for office 2013

[image]

Can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a repair on your office 2010 installation.

**EDIT**

More info here.  You are running Excel 2010 and Visio 2013.  Run the repair on 2010 should fix your Excel issue.  However you did not install the bits so that you can open it in Visio 2013 - and they don't co-exist as far as I know, you have to use one or the other.

Your alternative is to just download it from SharePoint and not attempt to open it from the Office Web Apps.

Comment: It does, but not in full - but running Excel 2010 and Visio 2013 will create some problems.  Doing the repair on 2010 will fix the Excel issue.  I'll clarify with an edit (but good or bad it was very much an answer not a question).

Comment: @JesusShelby thanks for the help. i did a repair for the office 2010 and the error message did not show again. but i have noted that the lync presence status stop working, so i repair the office 2013  and now the "open in visio" & "open in excel" and lync presence are working well. so should i consider the following procedure for all the users PCs. 1) remove sharepoint foundation feature from office 2013 . 2)repair offcie 2010 , restart the PC . 3) repair office 2013 , restart... does this sound valid from your point of view ?

Comment: I think that is valid.  Lync and SharePoint both have browser add-ons, and this really what you are "repairing".  When you first do 2010 it is most likely then deploying the presence add-on that isn't working correctly until you update back to 2013.  Just theory on Lync part as I have not validated first hand.